# Should WPF and WinForms Dispatcher be unified?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, winforms

I have an application which mixes *WPF* and *WinForm* controls as the project started long before WPF was available.
It is not possible to change all controls to be WPF based due to the amount of controls and the need to be backwards compatible for others which build further applications upon.

Now I sporadically face reentrancy problems which leads to *"Collection was modified"* exceptions because when we invoke a *WPF* dispatcher message it will lead due to the other pending WinForms messages to unexpected message pumping at *WinForms* side while we are dispatching a *WPF* message.

A typical callstack starts with a *WPF* invoke but ends up invoking BeginInvoke *WinForm* messages which alter the state of the UI. I can happen via event handlers that we change a *WPF* collection which are just at this moment enumerating.

….

```
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Wait(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherOperation operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
```

The actual *WPF* only code causing this looks innocent though:

```
UIDispatcher.Current  (this is WPF Dispatcher) .Invoke(new Action<string, …>(delegate(string msg, …)
        {
            this.statusModel.AddToStatus(msg, …);
        }), new object[]
        {
            message,
            icon
        });

   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
….
```

Is this behavior somewhere documented? 
Since I have *WinForm* and *WPF* code there is *WinForm* based code that uses the WinForm mechanisms to trigger execution in the UI Thread (ISynchronizeInvoke of System.Windows.Forms.Control).

This basically mixes *WPF* and *WinForms* dispatched messages. What is the recommended solution to get out of this mess? Should I change all *WinForms* Invoke/BeginInvoke calls with calls to *WPF* Dispatcher calls so we have a common message processing queue instead of two. Or is there a better way?

**Update 1**

The issues with mixing WPF and WinForms can be found also in more detail here:

- [Unexpected Window Message Pumping Part 2](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2014/10/12/159645.aspx)
- [Can You Execute Code While Waiting For A Lock?](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2014/10/07/159558.aspx)

Comment: Abandon all hope... wait so you run an action on the WPF dispatcher and that is somehow calling .Net code... which isn't running on the dotNet dispatcher, but the wpf one instead?

Comment: Why not execute your WPF dispatcher invoke call within a lambda passed into a WinForms invoke? Then all WPF invocations will be triggered from your WinForms message pump.

Comment: The WinForms message pump behavior is even worse. It will always execute all pending BeginInvoke messages and then continue with your synchronous action. That is actually the problem with Winforms. The problem is that if I invoke a WPF message it will trigger the Winforms dispatcher as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about nesting your invocation calls, so that all the calls are triggered deterministically from the message pump of your choice?

Something like this:

```
yourWinFormsControl.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        UIDispatcher.Current.Invoke(
            (Action)(() =>
            {
                this.statusModel.AddToStatus(xyz);
            }));
    }));
```

This creates an `Action` which does an invoke on the WPF dispatcher, but pushes it out to the WinForms dispatcher.

Comment: That will also cause Collection was modified exceptions. If WinForms Invoke is called it will execute all pending BeginInvoke calls which in turn can alter the ui state so that your foreach(var wpfItem in WPFCollection) { dispatcher.Invoke(....) } will break not because of your invoke call but by the forceful execution of other pending winforms messages.